# DotNetBar Scheduler / Calendar View Double-Click?

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar

I'm making an attendance editor for my school project. I am using DotNetBar for Windows Forms by DevComponents but I have a problem with the scheduler / calendar view.

**Let me give a bit of background...**

I have a database of timetables for teaching staff. It basically includes the classes to be taken at each period on each day by each staff user. On form load, these are loaded and added as appointments in the calendar.

I want it to be when you double click the class you are taking on that period (appointment) it executes the "Take Register" code.

Is it possible to do this? Any methods that you guys have to help me? Been looking for a couple of days now but I can't seem to solve my problem. I have a double-click method on the appointments but I can't get what appointment is clicked to know what class to take.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that. You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, I think I worked it out. For some reason you have to find the view that you are using first. This seemed a bit obscure so I'd thought I would share it with you.

I did `CalendarView1.DayView.SelectedItem.Text` which worked and returned the appointment text. Sorry if I wasted your time!

Comment: Not at all. I had never heard of that component. Welcome to Stack Overflow.